# php multi array create dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamically-generated

I have q question: what is the easiest way to create multi-dimensional array in php dynamically?

Here a static version:

```
$tab['k1']['k2']['k3'] = 'value';
```

I would like to avoid eval()
I'm not successful with variable variable ($$)
so I'm trying to develop a function fun with such interface:

```
$tab = fun( $tab, array( 'k1', 'k2', 'k3' ), 'value' );
```

Do you have a solution? What is the simplest way?

regards, 
Annie

Comment: Thanks a lot for all solutions. Other simple code is here (function setValueFromPath): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850744/how-to-reffer-dynamically-to-a-php-array-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, but here is one which uses PHP's ability to have N arguments passed to a function. This gives you the flexibility of creating an array with a depth of 3, or 2, or 7 or whatever.

```
// pass $value as first param -- params 2 - N define the multi array
function MakeMultiArray()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $output = array();
    if (count($args) == 1)
        $output[] = $args[0]; // just the value
    else if (count($args) > 1)
    {
        $output = $args[0];
        // loop the args from the end to the front to make the array
        for ($i = count($args)-1; $i >= 1; $i--)
        {
            $output = array($args[$i] => $output);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Here's how it would work:

```
$array = MakeMultiArray('value', 'k1', 'k2', 'k3');
```

And will produce this:

```
Array
(
    [k1] => Array
        (
            [k2] => Array
                (
                    [k3] => value
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following function will work for any number of keys.

```
function fun($keys, $value) {

    // If not keys array found then return false
    if (empty($keys)) return false;

    // If only one key then
    if (count($keys) == 1) {
        $result[$keys[0]] = $value;
        return $result;
    }

    // prepare initial array with first key
    $result[array_shift($keys)] = '';

    // now $keys = ['key2', 'key3']
    // get last key of array
    $last_key = end($keys);

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $val = $key == $last_key ? $value : '';
        array_walk_recursive($result, function(&$item, $k) use ($key, $val) {
            $item[$key] = $val;
        });
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if $tab always has 3 indices:

> function func(&$name, $indices, $value)
>     {
>     $name[$indices[0]][$indices[1]][$indices[2]] = $value;
>     };
>
> func($tab, array( 'k1', 'k2', 'k3' ), 'value' );