# Getting an array value based on a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following example data array:

```
$data = [];
$data["general"]["login"] = "Auth"
$data["general"]["login_failed"]["err1"] = "First error"
```

and the following request var:

```
$reqvar = "['general']['login']";
```

I'd like to:

```
print_r($data{$reqvar});
```

which would translate as

```
print_r($data['general']['login']);
```

but it doesn't seems to work

I'm not willing to iterate over the full array, it doesn't make sense considering that I know the path of the value that I want to print.

Thank you

Comment: its working only you have to add  semi-colon (;)  example - $data["general"]["login"] = "Auth";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reffer dynamically to a php ARRAY variable(s)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850744/how-to-reffer-dynamically-to-a-php-array-variables)

Comment: I've found the solution > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628176/using-a-string-path-to-set-nested-array-data/36042293#36042293

Answer (score 1):

First of all take a look on [PHP documentation - Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

"Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements (e.g. $array[42] and $array{42} will both do the same thing in the example above)."

So I think you are trying something like that:

```
<?php

$data = [];
$data["general"]["login"] = "Auth";
$data["general"]["login_failed"]["err1"] = "First error";

$reqvar1 = 'general';
$reqvar2 = 'login';

print_r($data{$reqvar1}{$reqvar2});
```

I strongly suggest you to refactor your code. Take a look on:

- [Clean Code book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)
- [Clean Code Blog](http://blog.cleancoder.com/)

Regards,

Comment: The $reqvar is needed to be dynamic

Answer (score -1):

Translate both values to dot notation and then you can select item into array. For example

```
$data["general"]["login"] = "Auth";
$data["general"]["login_failed"]["err1"] = "First error";
$data = convertToDotNotaion($data);
// it should looks like
$data["general.login"] = "Auth";
$data["general.login_failed"]["err1"] = "First error";
```

Then convert your came same way. And you can access to value use next code:

```
$data[$reqvarConverted}]
```

This is function **convertToDotNotaion** you should implement it yourself